# iOS temporary folder location issue

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios5, temp

I am saving my iOS application data to the temporary folder location. While upgrading my application, these data are getting deleted. But I need these data to be available for the next version as well. Is there any possibility of doing so. Please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using the temporary folder when the data is not temporary?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This functionality was developed earlier. At that time, it seems like those data were not necessary. But now we need those data mandatorily.

Comment: Er, don't use the temp folder?

Comment: It data is not temporary, then use Documents folder instead of Temporary. Files stored in Documents folder will not delete when upgrade your application.  You just need to change your path where you save you files.